# TeX editor for Ubuntu that generates PDFs?

Tags: pdf, emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

I am taking a  computer science course which requires completing assignments in PDF format. Many of the questions will require mathematical notation, so a TeX editor that can create PDFs would seem suitable for this purpose. Are there any TeX editors that can do this on Ubuntu? Are there any which work with Emacs23?

Comment: yes, lots! have a look at [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TeX file (or source or document) is a simple text document containing instructions about how to format/typeset the output. To this end a TeX document must be processed by a TeX engine (or TeX compiler) that transform the source, the instructions, into the text to be typeset. `pdflatex` is one specific TeX engine that produces a PDF files as the result of processing the instructions in a TeX document. In the simplest case you can use command line or a terminal window to call `pdflatex file.tex` to produce `file.pdf`. Most of the TeX friendly editors can do this for you (see [LaTeX Editors/IDE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339)])